# Putting a Cyrillic character in an R plot title: is there a command equivalent to "vfont"?

Tags: r, plot, title, cyrillic

I would like to add a Cyrillic character to a plot title, but seem to be missing some crucial piece of information. Using "expression(...)" isn't suitable as it doesn't have the characters I require.

I currently have an oldish mac running OS X 10.10.5 with

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

I can add Cyrillic to a plot, say

```
x<-runif(10,0,1); y<-runif(10,0,1); plot(x,y)

# first choose the Hershey font family
par(family="Hershey")
# The fifth table of demo(Hershey) to helps find the three digit code I need
# for my desired symbol, \366 .

# Adding the character to the plot proceeds by using a snippet found
# elsewhere to get an octal code:

code<-366
ocode <- 64*(code%/%100) + 8*(code%/%10)%%10 + code%%10 
string <- rawToChar(as.raw(ocode), multiple=TRUE)

# Adding the Cyrillic character to the plot is achieved by choosing the particular 
# face in Hershey I require using vfont
text(x=0.5,y=0.5,vfont=c("serif","cyrillic"),labels=paste("Cyrillic sample", string[1] ) )
```

However, I cannot seem to find an equivalent of "vfont" for the plot title. 
I've read many webpages and haven't seen this addressed. It could be that there's something subtle that I haven't understood. Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of hacky answer (but still an answer) that isn't very general or elegant. As I don't know much about fonts or unicode, this is probably as well as I can do in the short term. I will be very happy for a more general solution from someone who knows about such things.

Changing the font encoding solves the problem in this limited case

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_CTYPE", locale="ru_RU.KOI8-R")
quartz(); plot.new(); plot(z,y)
title(main="testing cyrillic \366")
[![An example plot with Cyrillic character in title][1]][1]
```

I'm sure there must be better ways of doing this, that don't require so much researching and playing around. Suggestions welcome!